# How do I conduct an F-test for change in R^2 within SAS?

Tags: regression, sas, f-test, multilevel-analysis

Suppose I have a simple model that looks something like this:

y = {Block 1} x1 x2 x3 x4 {Block 2} x5 x6 x7 x8

If I want to conduct an F-test to see whether Block 2 produces a significant change in R^2, how would I do that?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506140/sas-sequential-hierarchical-regression-change-in-r2-between-models-and-f-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the R^2 for the full model (X1-X8) called R^2c and the R^2 for the reduced (X1-X4) called R^2r.

F = [(R^2c-R^2r)/(8-4)]/[(1-R^2c)/(N-8-1)]

with 4 and N-8-1 df where N is the number of observations.

Comment: Thanks! Pardon my ignorance, but is there a name for this method? Or is this just literally what an F-test is?

Comment: I don't know of any special name. It is a test of the significance of the difference between two regression models. If the models differ it means leaving out X5-X8 signicantly lowers the R^2. You can find the equation expressed in terms of sums of squares here. http://onlinestatbook.com/2/regression/multiple_regression.html

Comment: @DavidLane, I believe that formula is the partial F test. OP may want to look into Partial $R^2$ as well.